# Should input parameters be an object or just multiple params

Tags: javascript, api, design-patterns

When I design an API that includes 5 input parameters, should the parameters be passed in in the form of objects, or just multiple params?

There is no relationship between parameters.

```js
const apiMethod = (parma1, parma2, parma3, parma4, parma5) => {……}
```

or

```js
let param = {parma1, parma2, parma3, parma4, parma5}
const apiMethod = (param) => {
  ...param
  // ……
}
```

which one is best？

Comment: It depends. Would the object be cohesive? In some cases you might have a mix.

Comment: thank you。Following your suggestion, I made the following changes:
1. Aggregate parameters according to their meanings. Some parameters that are only used for configuration are passed to the api in the form of objects.
2. Create a parameter class. The invocation of parameters is implemented through multiple different constructors.

Answer (score 0):

Always choose a single object or map over multiple params.

- you can add additional properties without breaking api
- you can put the params in any order
- the property names make the code self documenting
- you can define the object as a typescript type
- you dont have to worry about order to accomodate optional params
- you can extend or alter the type for other method calls.
- you can destructure the params to clean up code if needed.
- probably many more advantages, with not many disadvantages...